# when translated, what will these square brackets do?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I'm going through a source which depends on this definition

```
#define _SA_annotes3(n,pp1,pp2,pp3)    [SAL_annotes(Name=#n, p1=_SA_SPECSTRIZE(pp1), p2=_SA_SPECSTRIZE(pp2), p3=_SA_SPECSTRIZE(pp3))]
```

I'm used to function macros but having the whole body of the function enclosed in a square bracket is new to me. So taking this case and in any other normal function, what will be the use of enclosing the whole function body in a square bracket?

Comment: How is this macro used? Is it maybe turned into a string elsewhere?

Comment: Is this "plain" C++ or one of the Microsoft extensions (C++/CLI, C++/CX, ...)? In the latter case it might be a macro to simplify attribute usage

Comment: It's probably an extension to Microsoft's [source annotation language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182032.aspx), implemented as [user-defined attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd21828z.aspx) for C++/CX.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/09/bjarne-stroustrup-announces-cpp-core-guidelines

Answer (score 3):

This macro is part of SAL ([Microsoft source code annotation language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182032.aspx)), which is a static code analysis tool, running as preprocessor.

Comment: No, it isn't. The SAL annotations won't be placed inside brackets.

Comment: @IInspectable: Couldn't it be part of an attribute? `[_SA_annotes(a,b,c,d)]`

Comment: @IInspectable It's not part of the API that user should use, but it's definitely in SAL

Comment: @KerrekSB: [Attribute specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) in C++ use double brackets. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @IInspectable: Well, kind of: They use two consecutive single brackets. (Which is why structured bindings and constexpr lambdas and array bounds will provide fun to no end for future Stack Overflow answerers.)

Comment: it is in sal.h, the source I'm studying is not using it directly but there are definition which depends on other definitions which depends on this sal definition I posted in the question...
I want to understand very well what I'm doing so I was going to the roots of the definitions I was using...

Comment: @IInspectable: `_SA_annotes3()` is a SAL macro. It is not in Microsoft's version of SAL in Visual Studio (I don't see it in Microsoft's `sal.h` in VS2015, anyway), but it is in ReactOS's version of SAL (see [here](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d0/d0c/sal_8h_source.html)).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It is in Microsoft's implementation as well (*sal.h*). The definition of the OP is used, if `_USE_ATTRIBUTES_FOR_SAL` is defined. The only reference to that preprocessor symbol is in the [SAL Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402(v=vs.100).aspx) documentation for Visual Studio 2010. From that it's not entirely clear, what it does, though. It sounds like it was meant to be a performance optimization for static code analysis. Maybe it's no longer necessary, or "on" by default, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

@SomeWittyUsername is correct. But there is more. These brackets can be seen on macros such as *Use_decl_annotations*:

```
#define _SA_annotes0(n)                [SAL_annotes(Name=#n)]
#define _SA_annotes1(n,pp1)            [SAL_annotes(Name=#n, p1=_SA_SPECSTRIZE(pp1))]
...

#define _Use_decl_anno_impl_               _SA_annotes0(SAL_useHeader)
#define _Use_decl_annotations_         _Use_decl_anno_impl_
```

. Searching for that links to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/annotating-function-behavior?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019

which says:

> May be used on a function definition (also known as a function body) in place of the list of annotations in the header. When *Use_decl_annotations* is used, the annotations that appear on an in-scope header for the same function are used as if they are also present in the definition that has the *Use_decl_annotations* annotation.